# Null Exception was unhandled - IdleDetectionMode.Disabled

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Whenever I debug my windows phone app, whether it be on my phone or emulator I always get this Exception. How can I resolve this issue?

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

I'm still a beginner with this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's not a exception.

What I guess is the exception, is that the `PhoneApplicationService` isn't created. So you're getting a `NullReferenceException`.

Either add `PhoneApplicationService = new PhoneApplicationService()` on the line above, or ensure following XAML are in your App.xaml

```
<Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
    <!--Required object that handles lifetime events for the application-->
    <shell:PhoneApplicationService 
        Launching="Application_Launching" Closing="Application_Closing" 
        Activated="Application_Activated" Deactivated="Application_Deactivated"/>
</Application.ApplicationLifetimeObjects>
```

Answer (score 51):

I've had same issue. Clearing the \bin and \obj folders and then recompile solved it for me.

Comment: This in fact solved it for me! So no need to vote this one down.

Comment: Me too - heaven knows how long it would have taken me to solve this without this post.

Comment: Me too.. I chnaged the name of my assembly, and suddenly started getting this error. Rebuild Solution did not fix it. I followed your suggestion and it fixed it. Next time I should try Clean Solution, and Rebuild Solution probably.

Comment: I could reproduce this problem. If you change your AssemblyName project property, and build without cleaning the solution, you will get this error in Debug mode. Clean the solution (Build->Clean Solution in Visual Studio), and the problem will go away.